# I want to find my full activity in the app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Can I search my activity from web on app? ex. favorites, tags, questions?

I wish I can check my activity using the app.

Comment: In short: no. Use the web site for this. The app is meant for reading and posting, everything else is a "nice to have" bonus.

Comment: Yes.  I didn't find a way already. Thanks.